# How do I get the score distribution value for CoreNLP Sentiment?

Tags: stanford-nlp, stanford-nlp-server

I have setup CoreNLP server on my ubuntu instance and it works ok. I more interested in Sentiment module and currently I get is

```
{
sentimentValue: "2",
sentiment: "Neutral"
}
```

What I need is score distribution value, as you see here: http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/sentiment/rntnDemo.html

```
 "scoreDistr": [0.1685, 0.7187, 0.0903, 0.0157, 0.0068]
```

What am I missing or How do I get such data ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You need to get the a tree object via `SentimentCoreAnnotations.SentimentAnnotatedTree.class` from your annotated sentence. Then, you can get the predictions through the `RNNCoreAnnotations` class. I wrote the following self-contained demo code below that shows how to get the scores for each label of a CoreNLP Sentiment prediction.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.ejml.simple.SimpleMatrix;

import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations;
import edu.stanford.nlp.neural.rnn.RNNCoreAnnotations;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.Annotation;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP;
import edu.stanford.nlp.sentiment.SentimentCoreAnnotations;
import edu.stanford.nlp.trees.Tree;
import edu.stanford.nlp.util.CoreMap;

public class DemoSentiment {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final List<String> texts = Arrays.asList("I am happy.", "This is a neutral sentence.", "I am very angry.");
        final Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, parse, sentiment");
        final StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
        for (String text : texts) {
            final Annotation doc = new Annotation(text);
            pipeline.annotate(doc);
            for (CoreMap sentence : doc.get(CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class)) {
                final Tree tree = sentence.get(SentimentCoreAnnotations.SentimentAnnotatedTree.class);
                final SimpleMatrix sm = RNNCoreAnnotations.getPredictions(tree);
                final String sentiment = sentence.get(SentimentCoreAnnotations.SentimentClass.class);
                System.out.println("sentence:  "+sentence);
                System.out.println("sentiment: "+sentiment);
                System.out.println("matrix:    "+sm);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The output will be similar (some floating point rounding errors or an updated models might change the scores) to what is below.

For the first sentence `I am happy.`, you can see that the sentiment is `Positive`, and, the highest value in the returned matrix is `0.618`, at the fourth position, when interpreting the matrix as an ordered listing.

The second sentence `This is a neutral sentence.` has its highest score in the middle, at `0.952`, hence the `Neutral` sentiment.

The last sentence has correspondingly a `Negative` sentiment, with its highest score of `0.652` at the second position.

```
sentence:  I am happy.
sentiment: Positive
matrix:    Type = dense , numRows = 5 , numCols = 1
0.016  
0.037  
0.132  
0.618  
0.196  

sentence:  This is a neutral sentence.
sentiment: Neutral
matrix:    Type = dense , numRows = 5 , numCols = 1
0.001  
0.007  
0.952  
0.039  
0.001  

sentence:  I am very angry.
sentiment: Negative
matrix:    Type = dense , numRows = 5 , numCols = 1
0.166  
0.652  
0.142  
0.028  
0.012
```